# What does "own" mean in Linux "rpm" command manual

Tags: linux, rpm

I read the manual for rpm in CentOS and found the following sentence:

-f `<filename`> — queries the RPM database for which package **owns** `<filename`>. When specifying a file, specify the absolute path of the file (for example, rpm -f /bin/ls).

I am really confused by the word "own". Could anyone help?

Manual link: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-rpm-using.html

Comment: *Own* can mean "to be responsible for" and that's the intended meaning - the package is responsible for file X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate word in this context would be “provides”.

You give the command a filename and you get the package that made this file appear on your system.

It is also “owned” because removing the package will also remove the file.